# Dynamically loading a python module from a DLL with Boost.Python

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, python-module, python-c-api

I have a DLL written in C++ that uses Boost.Python to run Python code. The Python code should be able to interact with the actual application (in the DLL).
Is it possible to have both in one library or do I need to seperate the two?

So, DLL X calls Python code, Python code imports module Y, which is also located in DLL X.

Is this possible using the Python C API or (preferrably) Boost.Python? Something like `load_python_module("test", my_dll_handle)`...

I saw that the DLL exports PyInit_test, but I don't know if it's a good idea to just call this, and I don't even know what arguments it expects.

Answer (score 1):

The Python C-API docs strongly imply that this is possible (though I've never tried it myself), using the Python C-API [`PyImport_AppendInittab`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/import.html#PyImport_AppendInittab) function.  You call that function before `Py_Initialize` with the names and pointers-to-init-functions of the modules you want to import, and they'll be made available to the embedded code as if they were built-in modules (they still have to be imported).

Because the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(foo)` macro just creates an `initfoo()` function, you should be able to use this method with Boost.Python as well.

Comment: This looks perfect, thanks. I'll report back once I found some time to try this out.